# CSS Float Left and Right with Dynamic Width?

Tags: css, layout, dynamic, css-float

I'm trying to get two columns side by side (float left/right), but they both have dynamic text.

[image: screenshot]
!

[Link to code](https://jsfiddle.net/vR3eE/)

```
<div class="news-item">
    <div class="news-pic">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="" width="126" height="80" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="news-description">        
        <h3><a href="#">Long post title this is. What is this? this is a long post title. Even longer. (dynamic)</a></h3>   
        <a href="#" class="category-name">Longer category name (dynamic)</a>        
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <small><i>Published {{ post.published|date:"j. F Y" }}</i></small>
        <p class="text-min">Blah blah body</p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

```
html, body {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: arial;
}

.news-item {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    cursor: default;
    width: 658px;
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.news-pic {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: white;
}

.news-description {
    margin-left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 510px;
}

.news-description h3 {
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.news-description h3 a {
    text-decoration: none;    
    color: #137541;
}

.category-name {
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1px 4px 1px 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    border-right: none;
    background: rgba(215, 214, 214, .2);
    color: #807f7f;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;    
    margin-right: -11px;
    z-index: 5;
    float: right;
}
```

I'm trying to make the left main text "break" into a new line when it reaches the right category (which is also dynamic, so it can't be a static width). Is this at all possible with just CSS? Or do I have to reach for JS?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Can we see the Code please? :-)

Comment: I'm currently in the middle of fiddling with it so I'll update it in a couple of minutes. I want to find out if what I'm trying to achieve is even possible.

Comment: You should be able to do what you want to do by putting the markup for the button _before_ the title text, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Tried it just now but didn't do the trick. Maybe I'm floating them the wrong way. I've updated the question with a link to the HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the text is not floated, and the button is both floated right and before the text in HTML

http://jsfiddle.net/vR3eE/4/

Comment: Perfect! You nailed it. Thanks so much. :)